# Move to next cell when IF evaluates to FALSE

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

As title stated I'm trying to create an `IF` expression that only lists `true` results. If `false` then move to the next cell.

This is what I have, right now it returns false as 0.

```
A1=if('Packet Input'!$E2="UG",'Packet Input'!D2, 0)
```

What I need is If E2="UG" then A1=D2. If false, move down to E3 and run the logic check again. If E3="UG" then A1=D3. If not then once again move down to E4 and run the logic check.

Comment: What do you mean by "move to the next cell"?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to filter based on the formula result. Have you tried using the Filter option?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explaination. Let's say E2 is MA, and E3 is UG. So what I want is an equation that skips E2 and go down to E3 where it is "UG" and lists D3 in the first cell. That option doesn't work for me. I'm building a reference table for another table to link to. When I link it and drag down, all the non UG shows up.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a thorough example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change '0' to FALSE
2. User Filter function (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) on the results:

   =filter(A1:A20,A1:A20<>FALSE)

Answer (score -2):

It should be:

```
 A1=if('Packet Input'!$E2="UG",'Packet Input'!D2, FALSE)
```

Comment: This completely misses the point of re-running the logic check iteratively